# constrain image width in javascript link

Tags: javascript, image, hyperlink

How to constrain image width in javascript link? (As you would easily do in HTML.) The following code is not working. The image sources at 250px, so can't a width attribute be put in the script tag to constrain it to 191px? Thank you.

(I am using single quote marks here because the whole script tag code is contained within double quotes.)

```
<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript' src='http://www.dpbolvw.net/29102g73tvx-63wx9IOQJRNJM?target=_blank&mouseover=Y' width='191'></script>
```

Comment: A script tag isn't an element with dimensions. It has no width or height. Why are you trying to give it one?

Comment: just trying to give the image that is sourced, a width of 191, so it will fit properly in the area on the page where it appears.

Comment: You source images with `img` tags. That's a `script` tag. If the script is loading an image, then the width has to be set in the script or somehow passed via a querystring via the `src` attribute. (or, alternatively, set it via JS/CSS elsewhere)

Comment: Yes, that's what I was trying to do. Yes, I also tried putting width=191 as part of query string and that didn't work either. I know I could use an HTML link, but for other reasons, I wanted to try to use their javascript links, but needed to constrain width within each src/link. Guess my idea for doing it this way was not a good idea.

Comment: Passing the value via a query string only works if the script is looking for it. So, in your situation, if you don't have access to modify the script, then there's really no way to do what you want to do via the script tag. You could, however, wrap the script tag in a DIV such as  `<div id="myImage"><script...` and then set a width via CSS: `#myImage img {width: 300px;}`

Comment: thanks, DA, that's a good thought. I do already have a div wrapping the script, and it's width is set at 191px. The 250px banner simply overflows, though; it doesn't obey the containing div width. EDIT: wait, the DIV is set at 191, but give me a few minutes and I'll add a drill down so any img within the DIV is set at 191 ... just a few minutes..

Comment: DA: yes, that works, thank you. I had to reference the CSS in the stylesheet, rather than in-line CSS in the additional DIV, because I don't see any way of drilling the CSS down (from the DIV tag using in-line CSS) to capture styling of an image that comes to exist within that DIV tag. Thanks, again. Do I vote now? I'm new here.

Comment: Well, I didn't really answer your question, but provided a workaround. I'll move into a question if you'd like to vote it as the answer. I appreciate that!

Answer (score 0):

The script you're including is programmatically adding an `<img>` to your document:

> ```
> document.write("<a href=\"javascript:submitCJ10909759X391\
>     (\'CJ10909759X391\',null);\"><img src=\"http://www.yceml.net\
>     /0063/10909759-1.jpg\" width=\"250\" height=\"250\"\
>     alt=\"Travel related banner\" border=\"0\"/></a>");
> ```

You can modify the width of the image in one of two ways:

1. Modify the script that you're loading, or, if that's not possible;
2. Run your own script afterwards and use it to locate the `<img>` that was appended.

Unfortunately, the script doesn't give the `<img>` an `id` whereby you could easily find it in the DOM. If this is the way you want to go, I leave it up to you to find an alternative to locate the `<img>` in your DOM tree.

Comment: NB: I'm assuming you need the rest of the script to run as well. If that weren't the case you probably wouldn't post this question.

Comment: Yes, some of Groupon's 250px banners look fine when I scale them into 191px, to fit in my sidebar area, but the reasons for not using HTML are perhaps not important enough for overcoming this width issue of the script.

Answer (score 0):

Per the conversation we had, it looks like this JS is loading an image.

The only way to set a width attribute on this image would be for the script to support that feature, where you could perhaps pass it in as a querystring. Alas, it looks like this script does not do that.

My suggestion is to wrap the script tag (which renders an IMG tag) and then use CSS to handle the width:

```
<div id="myImage"><script.../></div>

#myImage img {width: 191px;}
```

Comment: well, apparently I don't have enough reputation to give you a positive vote. hmmphhh.